# Кнопка вверх, как в вконтакте

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет

Сразу скажу, перебрал уже много страниц, и сам пытался выдернуть ее из кода - все четно. В инете именно кнопки, т.е. не область большая и удобная, а кнопка в которую еле можно попасть.

В вконтакте - при прокрутке страницы вниз, на пол экрана с лева появляется область, высотой 100% и шириной где то 100-150 пикселей, которая при нажатии перемещает вверх страницы. Подскажите, как сделать такую кнопку?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понял вопрос.
Если он о том, как сделать саму область, то скорей всего это div с примерно таким набором свойств :

```
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 100%;
opacity: .6;
```

Если вопрос о методе, перемещающем вверх странице, то вот :

```
scrollTo(0,0)
```

Comment: вопрос о том, как эту показать, при положении экрана не в верху. т.к. у самого с этим проблемы вышли

Answer (score 2):

Верстате эту кнопку, скрываете. Далее - навешиваете [слушателя на scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/), а внутри проверяете [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/). И проверяете, больше ли это значение видимой высоты страницы. Если да - значит страница пролистана более чем на 1 видимую область, и тогда стоит показать кнопку. Если нет - соответственно, скрывать кнопку.
На самой кнопке scrollTop(0)